# Laravel gettext or native localization?

Tags: laravel, gettext

I would like to ask what and why would be the preferred tool for localizing Laravel projects? I have already used a gettext plugin and it worked well. I like using POedit which allows translators using it without programming skills. Plus, the translation hints are cool, too.

Is there any good reason for using Laravel native localization? Or, are there any cons of using gettext?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Why not both: GetText **and** native localization?

- Using GetText with **source text** is great for developers to work quickly and efficiently on new features without having to "make up" keys, switching files, maintaining consistency between keys and source text etc. Also, using GetText makes it easier to check if everything is translated and you don't need to worry if some keys/values are obsolete.
- Using PHP `trans()` with **keys/values** is great for copywriting. It's easy for the marketing team or CEO to change the text for all languages (included the source language) without changing the code.

For these reasons, we created https://translation.io/laravel that allows you to use both syntaxes at the same time (and we suggest to only use PHP key/value when the *source* text needs to be editable through the translation interface).

The package is here is you need more technical info: https://github.com/translation/laravel

Answer (score 1):

The native localization method is described in the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/localization). You basically maintain language files for all languages you want to translate to. To pull them out of the file, you use `trans()`, `trans_choice()` (for plural) or `__()` helpers in Blade template.

Thats the most basic translation handling. At one level higher you might want save all translations to the database. There exists a few packages on Github which doing this. Like:

- https://github.com/dimsav/laravel-translatable
- https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-translation-manager

and more. Just search for `Laravel Translation`.

This method only works as long as you use Blade for the frontend. If you use VueJs, Angular or React, the blade helpers won't work anymore and you have to find different ways how to handle this. This might depend on existent language handling of the aforementioned frontend framework.

I wrote an [blog article](https://medium.com/@konafets/localization-with-laravel-and-vuejs-e27068e68ee8) about that topic.

Comment: Thank you for the article, I am just checking it. Do you think that gettex is a good solution for a bigger project? Plus, translations in the DB or in files?

Comment: I guess Gettext with a translation server makes sense, when you have team 
or a translate office who has to translate all the strings. It is often found in the OpenSource world, where volunteers translate the programs.

There is not right or wrong, just if it does the job you have to get done.

Answer (score 1):

@Peter Matisko, can you give us a little update on how did you decide, which one are you preferring to use?

Personally I tried quite a couple of different translation libraries, but gettext is still first choice for me:

- extract all the translations from code and generate translation files (*.po)
- translations editor that runs on Mac, Windows and Unix (Poedit initial release ~20 years ago)
- translating plural forms

Comment: I like gettext too. POedit is cool for translations. I have the pro version which offers translation suggestions. Saves a lot of time. Plus, if possible, I'd like to avoid key-value translation approach, because it is much more difficult to read the code that uses keys.